# Is it possible to generate multiple complete commands with command substitution?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, command-substitution

There are many commands that accept multiple parameters, like `touch`, `ls` and `rm`. So that I can use the construct `{1..3}` to generate multiple parameters for the command. For example:

```
[root@192 ~]# touch file{1..3}
[root@192 ~]# ls file{1..3}
file1  file2  file3
[root@192 ~]# rm -f file{1..3}
[root@192 ~]#
```

Some commands don't support multiple parameters, like `groupadd`. So the following command generates an error:

```
[root@192 ~]# groupadd g{1..3}
Usage: groupadd [options] GROUP
...
[root@192 ~]#
```

Is it possible to generate multiple complete commands like `groupadd g1; groupadd g2; groupadd g3;`? I tried the following command, but failed:

```
[root@192 ~]# `"groupadd g"{1..3}`
bash: groupadd g1: command not found...
[root@192 ~]#
```

Btw, I'm a Bash new user and the example is just for demo purposes. I'm not trying to create a bunch of groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this.  One of the simplest and most obvious is to use a `for` loop.  For example:

```
for g in {1..3}; do groupadd "g$g" ...other groupadd args here... ; done
```

Note: unlike your `touch`, `ls`, and `rm` examples (which run the commands ONCE with multiple arguments, the expansion of `file{1..3}`), this runs `groupadd` THREE times, with one `"g$g"` argument each time.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way which is shorter than a `for` loop.

```
eval "groupadd g"{1..3}";"
```